# How do you untar multiple files into multiple subdirectory based on filename

Tags: bash, tar

I have a single tar file containing files (no folders)

```
0000107b869682826003b04a40e6394.txt
00029237482s8923789423ud8923892.txt
2c002y8378723887292377a79237649.txt
f598238209237408238742308374038.txt
```

how do I untar all the files such that they appear in subdirectories named after the first two chars of the files. So for the example above, it would create `00`, `2c`, and `f5` directories and each would have the following files.

```
00\0000107b869682826003b04a40e6394.txt
00\00029237482s8923789423ud8923892.txt
2c\2c002y8378723887292377a79237649.txt
f5\f598238209237408238742308374038.txt
```

Comment: According to the manpage, you can use `--transform=EXPRESSION` where `EXPRESSION` is a Sed expression, so something like `'--transform=s_^(..)_\1/_'` should work

Comment: Do you really mean backslash (`\ `)? Is this Windows? WSL?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the contents of the archive with `tar -tf archive.tar`, then use `tar -C` to extract the files in the desired directory:

```sh
while read -r f; do
    mkdir -p ${f:0:2} && tar xf archive.tar -C ${f:0:2} $f
done < <(tar -tf archive.tar)
```